# Not able to get the SONAR dashboard

Tags: java, maven

I am configuring sonar for my java project. I followed the below steps.

1. Downloaded the sonarqube 5.5 version and started it using StartSonar.bat
2. added the maven configuration(Plugin and profiles).
3. Right click on project and Run as maven build with sonar:sonar goal.

I am seeing the build is successful, but On my dashboard, I am not seeing anything. It shows only project name. And when I click on my project, It is showing the following page.
[image]

I am not able to see my sonar dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar uses its standard database after installation. You have to tell it first which DB it should use. This is defined in the config files:

%SONARINSTALLATION%\conf\sonar.properties

This file explains its behavior of using a standard DB until the user changes it.

Comment: I agree with you. My issue is with the Dashboard, after hitting the http://localhost:9000 it should show the dashboard right? That is missed. Am I missing anything in my configuration?

Comment: PS: I am able to see and access the dash board with Sonar 4.x version